# STRING_AGG not behaving as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017, string-aggregation

I have the following query:

```
WITH cteCountryLanguageMapping AS (
    SELECT * FROM (
        VALUES
            ('Spain', 'English'),
            ('Spain', 'Spanish'),
            ('Sweden', 'English'),
            ('Switzerland', 'English'),
            ('Switzerland', 'French'),
            ('Switzerland', 'German'),
            ('Switzerland', 'Italian')
    ) x ([Country], [Language])
)
SELECT
    [Country],
    CASE COUNT([Language])
        WHEN 1 THEN MAX([Language])
        WHEN 2 THEN STRING_AGG([Language], ' and ')
        ELSE STRING_AGG([Language], ', ')
    END AS [Languages],
    COUNT([Language]) AS [LanguageCount]
FROM cteCountryLanguageMapping
GROUP BY [Country]
```

I was expecting the value inside Languages column for Switzerland to be comma separated i.e.:

```
  | Country     | Languages                                 | LanguageCount
--+-------------+-------------------------------------------+--------------
1 | Spain       | Spanish and English                       | 2
2 | Sweden      | English                                   | 1
3 | Switzerland | French, German, Italian, English          | 4
```

Instead I am getting the below output (the 4 values are separated by `and`):

```
  | Country     | Languages                                 | LanguageCount
--+-------------+-------------------------------------------+--------------
1 | Spain       | Spanish and English                       | 2
2 | Sweden      | English                                   | 1
3 | Switzerland | French and German and Italian and English | 4
```

What am I missing?

---

Here is another example:

```
SELECT y, STRING_AGG(z, '+') AS STRING_AGG_PLUS, STRING_AGG(z, '-') AS STRING_AGG_MINUS
FROM (
    VALUES
        (1, 'a'),
        (1, 'b')
) x (y, z)
GROUP by y

  | y | STRING_AGG_PLUS | STRING_AGG_MINUS
--+---+-----------------+-----------------
1 | 1 | a+b             | a+b
```

Is this a bug in SQL Server?

Comment: Seems to be a bug, it's always returning the 1st STRING_AGG no matter how you write the CASE

Comment: This is a beauty of an optimizer bug. Simpler and more striking repro: `CASE COUNT([Language]) WHEN 1234567 THEN STRING_AGG([Language], ' and ') ELSE STRING_AGG([Language], ', ') END AS [Languages]` (uses the `1234567` case) and `CASE COUNT([Language]) WHEN 1234567 THEN STRING_AGG([Language], ' and ') END AS [Languages]` (leave out `ELSE` -- now the match fails and the expression becomes `NULL`). No matter what the "correct" result should be, surely that's not it.

Comment: Not sure this is appropriate, but....LOL! Since this is not a lack of knowledge on your part, rather than a real thing that many would come across, I strongly recommend changing the question title to be more accurate than a generic "not working as intended", in order to maximize benefit for all.

Comment: In the resulting execution plan, the second `STRING_AGG` is entirely missing and instead the expression is rebound to the first one, as if the `CASE` had said `STRING_AGG([Language], ' and ')` twice. Any subsequent `CASE`s are absorbed as well. Looks like something very weird is going on with subexpression elimination.

Comment: This bug seems to be specifically tuned to `STRING_AGG`. If the `ELSE` is changed to `'blargh' + STRING_AGG(...)`, you'll get `'blarghFrench and German...`, so it improperly unifies the second `STRING_AGG` with the first. The simplest workaround is to change the `ELSE` expression to `STRING_AGG([Language] + '', ', ')` -- this defeats CSE, suggesting there's a bug where CSE ignores the second argument to `STRING_AGG`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert That workaround sounds like it would make a good answer.

Comment: I'd like to add that the query works as expected in Azure SQL Database so hopefully a fix for the on-prem is in the works.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, this is a Bug (tm), present in all versions of SQL Server 2017 (as of writing). It's fixed in Azure SQL Server and 2019 RC1. Specifically, the part in the optimizer that performs common subexpression elimination (ensuring that we don't calculate expressions more than necessary) improperly considers all expressions of the form `STRING_AGG(x, <separator>)` identical as long as `x` matches, no matter what `<separator>` is, and unifies these with the first calculated expression in the query.

One workaround is to make sure `x` does not match by performing some sort of (near-)identity transformation on it. Since we're dealing with strings, concatenating an empty one will do:

```
SELECT y, STRING_AGG(z, '+') AS STRING_AGG_PLUS, STRING_AGG('' + z, '-') AS STRING_AGG_MINUS
FROM (
    VALUES
        (1, 'a'),
        (1, 'b')
) x (y, z)
GROUP by y
```

Comment: I allowed myself to post this workaround on [Azure Feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/35803012-string-agg-multiple-string-agg-columns-defer-to)

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/257819/23463 indicates it is still broken, even in CU17.

Comment: @RossPresser: retested it and sure enough, CU17 doesn't actually fix this. Amended the answer.