# SQL Server - STRING_AGG separator as conditional expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017, string-aggregation

I need to concatenate rows using different separator based on arbitrary logic. For instance:

```
CREATE TABLE t(i INT, c VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO t(i,c) VALUES(1, 'a'),(2, 'b'),(3, 'c'),(4, 'd'),(5, 'e');

SELECT STRING_AGG(c,(CASE WHEN i%2=0 THEN ' OR ' ELSE ' AND ' END)) 
       WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY i) AS r
FROM t;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c878b8bf759971645c25cb797c03dc55)**

And it ends with error:

> Separator parameter for STRING_AGG must be a **string literal** or **variable**.

My end goal is to get: `a OR b AND c OR d AND e` like in: **[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=1ff9615f1101bff256196fb14e0c0040)**

---

Notes: I am aware of `XML + STUFF` or `@var = @var + ...`.

I am searching for "workarounds" specific to `STRING_AGG`.

---

EDIT: I've added it as sugestion on [Azure Feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/36809734-string-agg-with-non-constant-expression-as-separat)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this cannot be done, but if it could be done, you would most like hit [the bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52534215/11683) anyway.

Comment: @GSerg Thanks for bringing this up. I am aware of that bug and it is already on Azure Feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Just reverse the order and use stuff and you can eliminate the need for a cte and most of the string functions:

```
SELECT STUFF(
           STRING_AGG(
               (IIF(i % 2 = 0, ' OR ', ' AND '))+c
           , '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY i)
           , 1, 5, '') AS r
FROM t;
```

Results: `a OR b AND c OR d AND e`

[**db<>fiddle demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d87e9ff227da7955d704d8a51dc25d12)

Since the first row `i % 2` equals `1`, you know the `string_agg` result will always start with `and`: `and a or b...`
Then all you do is remove the first 5 chars from that using `stuff` and you're home free.

I've also taken the liberty to replace the `CASE` expression with the shorter `IIF`

**Update**

Well, in the case the selected separator is not known in advance, I couldn't come up with a single query solution, but I still think I found a simpler solution than you've posted - separating my initial solution to a cte with the `string_agg` and a select from it with the `stuff`, while determining the length of the delimiter by repeating the condition:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT MIN(i) As firstI,
       STRING_AGG(
               (IIF(i % 2 = 0, ' OR ', ' AND '))+c
           , '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY i)
       AS r
FROM t
)

SELECT STUFF(r, 1, IIF(firstI % 2 = 0, 4, 5), '') AS r
FROM CTE;
```

[**db<>fiddle demo #2**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=67b7092485ea76229038f74465ee22f9)

Comment: I like this aproach. Single-level query is always more reliable and easier to read. The only minor drawback is that I have to use same length of delimeter (' OR '/' AND ') when I got cases were I am unable to determine which goes first. Here is simplified scenario i%2 so we could use hardcoded 5.

Comment: That is a drawback. I had a feeling my idea was so simple you should have thought about it yourself...I've updated my answer.

Comment: The other solution is to pad separator with trailing spaces up to longest possible separator. Ugly but it will work

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution(not ideal) is to move separator to the main expression and set separator as blank:

```
-- removing last separator
WITH cte AS (
SELECT STRING_AGG(c+(CASE WHEN i%2=0 THEN ' OR ' ELSE ' AND ' END), '')
    WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY i)AS r
FROM t
)
SELECT r, REPLACE(REPLACE(r+'$', ' OR $', ''), ' AND $', '') AS r
    ,STUFF(r,
           LEN(r)-CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(TRIM(r)))+1, 
           CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(TRIM(r)))+1,
           '') AS r
FROM cte;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e17f99c9cc8bec35102b7b9f662a6208)**